# Android-playing videos

Tags: android

Can someone tell me how does the imdb app manage to play trailers on android. I know we can play 3 gp but then it is of very low quality.I would want to play videos from youtube or other sources without using a webview 
I am not sure if this question belongs here but it would be great if you could point me in the right direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this project for playing Youtube video: [android-youtube-player](http://code.google.com/p/android-youtube-player/)

You can easily modify OpenYouTubePlayerActivity to play other the streaming url´s aswell.

Answer (score 1):

You can also play/stream mp4 video.

example:

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/media/MediaPlayerDemo_Video.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you able to play video via url by using videoView controll.
 Thanks